# Printer Naming Convention

Tags: naming-conventions, printers, printer-properties

Can we get Printer information such as mono or color from its Make and Model Number .
Is there any naming convention exists ?
For the model like Lexmark,Canon,Toshiba,HP  is there any naming convention exist   ?
Any help will be appreciated 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Whether there's a naming convention among manufacturers or not, printers can be renamed by users to be anything they want.  It's possible to find out a whether a printer is color or mono, but not from its name.  Are you willing to consider other methods?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, Lexmark at least doesn't seem to include the color information on their printer models - M* is probably mono, T* is probably mono, C* is probably color, but X* can be either.

It's probably best, when writing descriptions of the printers on your network, to include the desired information. ("Color inkjet in the lobby of building A").

Comment: Hmm... but do all printer  follow any naming convention for mono and color.. if they can you tell me

Comment: My assumption is, since even the first one I checked doesn't have a convention, then there's no way there's a common naming convention across companies.